# Adding .crt to Spring Boot to enable SSL

Tags: spring, tomcat, ssl, spring-boot, https

I have never done this before, and most of the tutorials do not mention how to deal with .crt files.

I bought an SSL certificate from GoDaddy, and selected Tomcat as a platform when downloading it. The zip file contained 3 files:

```
dea08asdjakjawl.crt  
gd_bundle-g1-g1.crt  
gdig.crt.pem
```

I have a running Spring Boot application (on port 80 with an embedded Tomcat) on a CentOS7 server. (Server is running on Digital Ocean, it has an assigned domain, and works with simple http)

I would like to switch it to https://something.com

All the tutorials suggest that I must have a .jks or a .p12 file for that, but I wasn't able to convert the .crt files to that. Beside I am not sure which of the 2 .crt file is the one I should convert to .jks/.p12.

I have added this to my application.yaml, but didn't help:

```
server:    
  port: 443  
  ssl:  
    enabled: true  
    key-alias: server  
    key-store: "cert.crt"  
    key-store-password: "***"
```

How can I change my running Spring Boot project to accept HTTPS queries using this certificate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the correct procedure was the following:

I had to recreate the CSR from scratch, using a Java Key Store instead.

```
keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore KeyStore.jks -keysize 2048
```

Then a new CSR:

```
keytool -certreq -alias mydomain -keystore KeyStore.jks -file mydomain.csr
```

That had to be resent to the cert provider to generate a new .cer file. So they sent me back the mentioned 2 .cer files, the "bundle" one was the intermediate .cer, which I needed to add like this:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file intermediate.crt -keystore KeyStore.jks
```

Then the actual "long-named" .cer file like this:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mydomain -file mydomain.crt -keystore KeyStore.jks
```

Then this is something which can be converted to p12 like this:

```
 keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <MY_KEYSTORE.jks> -destkeystore <MY_FILE.p12> -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass <PASSWORD_PKCS12> -srcalias <ALIAS_SRC> -destalias <ALIAS_DEST>
```

Finally the application.properties needed extra lines and became something like this:

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.enabled=true
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=domain
server.ssl.key-password=password
```

And it is finally working.

Comment: Hi I am getting the below exception when i start the application, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big. Any suggestions?

Comment: For 3rdd step to use intermediate.crt it is not generating.

Comment: Error :- keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: intermediate.crt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Hi, What <ALIAS_SRC> and <ALIAS_DEST> should be. I assume <ALIAS_SRC> should be related to one of the aliases created in previous step.

Comment: For me also extraction of pricate key from p12 was required: openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12  -nodes -nocerts -out key.pem

Comment: difference between server.ssl.key-store-password and server.ssl.key-password
and what should be the <ALIAS_SRC> and <ALIAS_DEST>

Comment: @Macskasztorik  what should be the server.ssl.key-alias ?? Also what is the difference between server.ssl.key-store-password and server.ssl.key-password and what should be the <ALIAS_SRC> and <ALIAS_DEST> Pls reply...

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem before when working with Spring Boot. The Certificate Authority sent me a folder consists of:

- domain-name.crt (certificate file generated against the domain name)
- bundle.crt (contains CA root and/or intermediate certificates [reference](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/986/69/what-is-ca-bundle). For details about CA root and intermediate certificates [click here](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/root-certificates-intermediate/).

Spring Boot only understands certificate files in .JKS / PKCS12. We need to convert .CRT file into a .JKS format file. Here are the steps:

1. Convert certificate to PKCS12 format
   `openssl pkcs12 -export -in <domain-name.crt> -inkey </path-to private.key> -name <alias-name> -out <domain-name.p12>`. This will generate a .p12 file
2. Import PKCS12 file in JKS keystore
   `keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass <pass-phrase> -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore <your .p12 file> -srcstoretype PKCS12`. A file with .jks extension will be created.
3. Import CA bundle certificate into JKS keystore
   `keytool -import -alias <alias-name> -trustcacerts -file <bundle.crt> -keystore keystore.jks`

Note:

> **Private.key** is a key that you generate for the CA to use it for certificate issuing.
> **pass-phrase** is a password that protect your private key. That you provide will creating the private.key. [For more info](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/openssl-tutorial-ssl-certificates-private-keys-csrs)

Finally copy .jks file to your project `/resource` folder and update `application.properies` file.

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=<pass-phrase>
server.ssl.key-alias=<alias-name>
```

And it should work.

Comment: Hi, I am frustated about this problem, and everyone out there suggest to create own SSL. But, your solution work. Anyway, I can use .p12 file from your [1] step directly instead of using JKS file. So, it didn't need private key. Thank you.

Comment: thank you! This solved the problem for me (i was using the ssl certificate by cloudlfare)

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a keystore and a trusstore(or use default trusstore provided by java). keystore will contain your private key and server certificate. truststore will contain your ca certificate.
to create a p12 keystore-

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in [path/to/certificate] -inkey [path/to/privatekey] -certfile [path/to/ca/certificate ] -out keystore.p12
```

enter a password for keystore. configure this keystore in your application.yaml.

For trust-store entry, if using java's default trust-store then add your ca certificate to ...jre/lib/security/cacerts

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file ca.crt -keystore cacerts
```

or you can create trusstore then configure this truststore in your application.yaml

all keytool commands you can easily find on internet to convert/create/import/export/list...

Provided 3 files you can check which is which- 
1. should be your certificate
2. should be ca certificate chain

Comment: Is my private key (which is needed for the keystore) the .pem file?
By " configure this keystore in your application.yaml" do you mean I should take the exported .p12 file and define it's location in the .yaml file instead of the .crt file? Thanks

Comment: It can be pem or pkcs format, you need to check which is your private key. If you sent csr to GoDaddy for creating certificate then you must have created private key. If godaddy is creating your key also then they must have provided you. pem private key start with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY so you can open file in text editor and check. If files are in pkcs format then either you can read using openssl command or convert them to pem using openssl.
Yes, p12 or jks keystore/trustore need to be used instead direct crt file

Comment: Could you please tell me the difference between the server and the ca certificate. I issued a csr to a CA , and received a .crt (just one) file, which had the same public key as in my csr.

Comment: I would also add that when using the openssl command to add the -name argument. This equates to the alias in the keystore file. So the full command would be `openssl pkcs12 -export -in [path/to/certificate] -inkey [path/to/privatekey] -certfile [path/to/ca/certificate ] -out keystore.p12 -name [alias-name]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want Openssl to be added to spring boot.

Follow below steps if you already installed openssl software.
//create key and public certificate

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.pem
```

//test

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in certificate.pem
```

//combine key and public certificate

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey key.pem -in certificate.pem -export -out certificate.p12
```

//test

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -noout -info
```

In spring boot properies add below

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:certificate.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
```

[reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.cmc.doc/task_apionprem_gernerate_self_signed_openSSL.html)

Answer (score 2):

good news
with SpringBoot 3.1+

application.properties

```
//for server
server.port=443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.certificate=file:/certs/tls.crt
server.ssl.certificate-private-key=file:/certs/tls.key

//for management
management.server.port=9090
management.server.ssl.enabled=true
management.server.ssl.certificate=file:/certs/tls.crt
management.server.ssl.certificate-private-key=file:/certs/tls.key
```

Answer (score -2):

If using Java, one generates the private key and the CSR using the `keytool` command using the `-keystore` parameter. I admit that I do not know if and how it is possible to import existing ones into a keystore (`keytool` allows import of certificates), but there might be a way.

In the worst case scenario, re-generate the CSR with key tool and re-generate the SSL/TLS certificates again - it should come at no extra cost.

Comment: I can import .crt files into a fresh keystore, but which of the 2 certificates should I import there? Is it a problem if the keystore is fresh and new? How can I make a .p12 file from it?