# Spring Boot SSL IllegalArgumentException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I just tried to install my certificate from DigiCert to activate SSL on SpringBootApplication using method in this page : https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/. I did it step by step, but I set the configuration programatically instead of using properties file.

```
SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(PosDetailServer.class);
Map<String, Object> defaults = new HashMap<>();
if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("https")) {
    defaults.put("server.ssl.key-store", args[1]);
    defaults.put("server.ssl.key-store-password", "password");
    defaults.put("server.ssl.key-store-type", "PKCS12");
    defaults.put("server.ssl.key-alias", "tomcat");
    defaults.put("server.ssl.key-password", "password");
}
defaults.put("server.port", "8181");
springApplication.setDefaultProperties(defaults);
springApplication.run(args);
```

When I tried to run it, I got error:

> IllegalArgumentException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.

Whats wrong with the step? How can I fix it?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148884/spring-boot-https-pkcs12-derinputstream-getlength-lengthtag-111-too-big too

Answer (score 0):

After looking around, I found in some information that happened because of actually `keytool` **make a JKS instead of PKCS12**. So I change the configuration to:

```
    defaults.put("server.ssl.key-store-type", "JKS");
```

And another error happened:

> java.io.IOException: Alias name tomcat does not identify a key entry

So I am started to look another solution and I found enough information that I need to include the *private key* in the JKS, which is I don't have it. But in PKCS12, it is not needed. So I started to search how can I get PKCS12 using existing crt file.

Finally I dropped into this question: [Adding .crt to Spring Boot to enable SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670046/adding-crt-to-spring-boot-to-enable-ssl) and an answer there worked, just need little modification.

So, I just need to export PKCS12 file using my current crt file using `openssl`

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <domain-name.crt> -inkey </path-to private.key> -name <alias-name> -out <domain-name.p12>
```

Hope this helped.